# How to make a Thread that loads images?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading

I'am really new to programming and java and I'am developing a wallpaper app for android using eclipse and I can't add a lot of photos since the main thread can't handle all these stuff so I tired to make a new Thread so I can put photos but I can't I don't know what I should write in the run method. so if you can tell me what I should write and what to change and with an example if possible that would be great, Thanks.

P.S: please don't suggest using AsyncTask because I don't know how to use it.

and here is my code:

```
public class SET2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageView display;
int toPhone2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.set2);


    toPhone2 = R.drawable.iv1;
    display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageV1);
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IView1);
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IView2);
    ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IView3);
    ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IView4);
    ImageView image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IView5);
    ImageView image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IView6);
    Button setwall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

    image1.setOnClickListener(this);
    image2.setOnClickListener(this);
    image3.setOnClickListener(this);
    image4.setOnClickListener(this);
    image5.setOnClickListener(this);
    image6.setOnClickListener(this);
    setwall.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.IView1:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv1);
        toPhone2 = R.drawable.iv1;
        break;
    case R.id.IView2:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv2);
        toPhone2 = R.drawable.iv2;
        break;
    case R.id.IView3:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv3);
        toPhone2 = R.drawable.iv3;
        break;  
    case R.id.IView4:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv4);
        toPhone2 = R.drawable.iv4;
        break;
    case R.id.IView5:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv5);
        toPhone2 = R.drawable.iv5;
        break;
    case R.id.IView6:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv6);
        toPhone2 = R.drawable.iv6;
        break;
    case R.id.button5:
        Toast addEggs = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        addEggs.show();
        InputStream WP = getResources().openRawResource(toPhone);
        Bitmap wallpaper = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(WP);
         DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
         getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
         int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
         int width = metrics.widthPixels;
         Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), toPhone);
         Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap,width,height, true);
         WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this); 
         wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
         wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);

        try{
            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(wallpaper);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Where is your thread code?  I don't see the base even there.  That said, I'd probably suggest you use [`AsyncTask`](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask) instead of the java threads for this (it adds some nice abstractions for you).

Comment: @nerdwaller i don't know how to use AsyncTask, and I removed everything that included the Thread coding since I don't know which is right and which is wrong

Comment: I linked a solid tutorial for you, give it a shot.  If you are still interested in using the `Thread` way, post the code so we can see what issues there are and give some feedback, rather than writing it for you.

Comment: So *learn* to use `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I can't understand it, @chrylis

Answer (score 0):

First, avoid huge switch statements.

Second, The best way is to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

However, a simple quick way you can make a new thread is like this:

```
...
case R.id.button5:
    Toast addEggs = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    addEggs.show();

Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
       final Bitmap  bmWallpaper = loadImage(id);
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
       public void run() {
          setWallpaperBitmap(bmWallpaper);    
       }
    });
});
t.start();
break;
    }
}

private Bitmap loadImage(int id) {
    InputStream WP = getResources().openRawResource(id);
    Bitmap wallpaper = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(WP);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), toPhone);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap,width,height, true);
    return bitmap;
}

private void setWallpaperBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
   try{
        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
        getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(wallpaper);
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Never do this!  Handle your exceptions
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer seems pretty helpful but there is a problem, eclipse says that this line "setWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap)" (Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from ContextWrapper)

Comment: Oops.  "setWallpaper" is already a method on Context.  I just renamed it to setWallpaperBitmap.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#setWallpaper(java.io.InputStream)